# Course.aggregate is not a function in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a model like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CourseSchema = new Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
  title: String,
  overview: String,
  price: Number,
  free: Boolean,
  published: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  profilePhoto: String,
  coverPhoto: String,
  course_preview_img: String,
  course_preview_video: String,
  duration: String,
  lessons: String,
  access: String,
  category: String,
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});

CourseSchema.method({});

CourseSchema.static({});

mongoose.model('Course', CourseSchema);
```

I have query like this:

```
const courses = await Course.aggregate() //Error here
.lookup({
    from: 'User',
    localField: 'user',Course,
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'user'
})
.lookup({
    from: 'EnrolledCourses',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'course',
    as: 'enrolled_courses'
})
.limit(req.query.limit || 10)
.sort({ createdAt: -1 })
.exec()
```

As per this doc [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#Aggregate.prototype.pipeline()) and [here](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/aggregate), it should work but not sure why it is throwing error

Comment: Did you import the Course model correctly? Can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using:

`await mongoose.model('Course').aggregate()`